# SMTP: How to send Emails from Pickup Directory

Tags: c#, smtp

My C# application is sending emails using SMTP. I put the emails first to a pickup folder. However, what do I need now to send those emails(.eml files) from that folder?

```
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.SpecifiedPickupDirectory;
client.PickupDirectoryLocation = "C:\\mails";
```

Thank you.

Comment: Are you talking about .eml files?

Comment: yes, i need to find a way to those .eml files